# How can I plant assembly instructions in the prologue and epilogue of function via gcc

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

I try to build profiler to some c project.
I want that gcc plant some assembly instruction in all the function entries and function exit points in compile time.
I try to search some guides in the web but without success.
where can I learn how to do that?

thank in advance.

Comment: how about using gperf?

Comment: I want to build the profiler - this is my studies project :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently you can use the `-finstrument-functions` flag to get gcc to generate instrumentation calls

```
void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *func, void *callsite); 
void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void *func, void *callsite);
```

at function entry and exit. I've never used this, but a quick search brings up information and examples [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-finstrument_002dfunctions-2114), [here](http://linuxgazette.net/151/melinte.html), [here](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/) and [here](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2010/09/gcc-function-instrumentation.html).

Comment: Also note the `no_instrument_function` attribute, which can be used on the cyg_profile functions themselves to prevent infinite recursion.

Comment: Absolutely - I'd highly recommend getting a good handle on the online documentation and examples available beforehand - as I said, never used it personally, but it does look like the kind of thing that's likely to have a number of hidden pitfalls associated with it!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to modify `gcc` (which is non-trivial!), I would think that there are two fairly obvious approaches.

1. Pre-process the C code itself - it's not easy, but not terribly hard either. Find the beginning and end of a function, and add your code to it, then let the compiler proper do the job of making the code... There are quite a few tools on the market that does this in one way or another, for a variety of purposes [code flow analysis, profiling, etc].
2. Take the assembler output of gcc and process it to to add code to functions there. This is in some ways easier, and in some ways harder. Identifiying functions is probably no more difficult, but "not breaking" the assembler code may be harder unless your inserted assembler code is completely "safe".

Obviously, the option of modifying `gcc` is also a possibility, but the compiler code is fairly complex, and unless you basically take all the existing hooks for `gprof`, I don't think it's a school project - unless you are on your way to a PhD or some such.